# Java SQL Incorrect Integer Value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

Here is my error: SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'age' for column 'age' at row 1

The field that is giving me the problem is the first Int field in the table.

Here is the code I am using:

The data:

```
   String username = "test1";
    String id="test1";
    String firstName="Testname";
    String lastName="Testnamer";
    String address="Testadd";
    String phone="Test0851459574";
    String email="Testemailee";
    int age = 24;
    char sex='M';
    double height=1.23;
    int kgs=125;
    double stone=5.75;
    int targetWeightKgs=34;
    double bmi=4.34;
    String medicalHistory="testertester";
    String extraHistory="testertestertest";
    boolean smoker=true;
    boolean usernameCompleted=true;
    String myNotes="testnotes";
         UsersDatabase.insertMember(username,id,firstName,lastName,address,phone,email,age,sex,height,kgs,stone,targetWeightKgs,bmi,medicalHistory,extraHistory,smoker,usernameCompleted,myNotes);
```

in the insertMember method:

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO Members " + "VALUES      ('username','id','firstName','lastName','address','phone','email','age','sex','height','kgs','stone','targetWeightKgs','bmi','medicalHistory','extraHistory','smoker','usernameCompleted','myNotes')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Here is the table screenshot: http://snag.gy/VuMpO.jpg

Comment: Are you literally trying to insert `'age'`? Or would that actually be `42` or something in your real code? Because as is, your `age` field is an int, and you're trying to stuff a 3-character string into it.

Comment: age is an integer, so insert there an int such as 5 or so

Comment: You should be using a prepared statement, and specifying the parameter values...

Comment: java don't supports magic quotes as php do.

Comment: Agree with **Jon Skeet**, it is also to avoid SQL injection attack. You need to change the code, if you don't there will be a big hole in your code. Here is 
[Prepared Statement API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to create a query via preparedStatement where you can use the variables and then execute the update.

You should do something like:

```
PreparedStatement st = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Members VALUES  ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?'','?','?','?','?','?'");
st.setString(1, username);
st.setString(2, id);
```

It goes on, and, when you want to set an int:

```
st.setInt(8, age);
```

After all the values have been set, you have to execute:

```
st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: It is in the package java.sql.PreparedStatement. You should be able to use it without external libraries.

Comment: QL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (6 > number of parameters, which is 5).

Comment: Could you paste the statement?

Comment: OK. Sorry about that, it is not "'?'" but "?" (without '). My mistake (and a big one). Sorry. I should have tested the code before posting.

Comment: Could you do a paste bin of what you mean, I don't understand :)

Answer (score 1):

remove '' from all int's as int are inserted without single quotes.
So your sql is :

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO Members " + "VALUES      ('username','id','firstName','lastName','address','phone','email',age,'sex',height,kgs,stone,targetWeightKgs,bmi,'medicalHistory','extraHistory','smoker','usernameCompleted','myNotes')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Or you can use something like this also :

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `table`
        (pid,tid,rid,tspend,description) VALUE 
        (?,?,?,?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1, pid );
pstmt.setString(2, tid);
pstmt.setString(3, rid);
pstmt.setInt(4, tspent);
pstmt.setString(5,des );
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Using prepared statement is a better way to execute sql in java

Comment: Sorry, but with the first example... are you not inserting "username", "id", age", etc. instead of the variable's value?

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support string interpolations, currently 'username' is interpreted as a literal string. If you do not wish to use a prepared statement, consider using `String.format` to generate the values to be inserted.

```
String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO MEMBERS VALUES ('%s', %d, '%s')", username, id, firstname);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Using a solution like this leaves you open to SQL injection and other vulnerabilities, but I think it is perfectly acceptable if you are playing around with JDBC and trying to understand it.